# Robust and easy way of running MQL Freebase queries from Android

Tags: android, json, httpwebrequest, freebase, mql

I need your help again. If I go to http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor/  and run a simple query, let's say:

```
[{
    "type":          "/time/month",
    "name":          [{}],
    "month_number":  null,
    "calendar_system": "Gregorian calendar",
    "sort":          "month_number"
}]
```

The results are returned fine. Now, I want to make the same thing, but call this from an Android application. As I see it, the query is a JSON string so my guess is that I could use a library like GSON to handle calls and responses. Is there a more simple way ?

Thank you for your time.

LE: it seems that according to their wiki

> Note: Our read APIs have moved into Google Code. We recommend that all
>   developers switch over to these new APIs to make sure that they
>   benefit from all the latest features and bug fixes. See the API
>   Changes page for details.

I have searched around but couldn't manage to get an idea. Their website is awful in providing java samples. On Google api on googlecode I can't find something to guide to. Please help as I am stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Java libraries for Freebase which may give you a slightly higher level of abstraction:

https://github.com/narphorium/freebase-java-api (uses StringtreeJSON)
http://code.google.com/p/freebase-java/source/browse/ (uses org.json.simple)

(From http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Java a good source of information on Freebase)

Comment: Some of the libraries are not compatible anymore with the API but digging around the website you mentioned, found a good reference: http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API